# CodeDom not using MemberAttributes

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

When trying to learn CodeDom under Ms visual studio, I noticed that the code generation seems to ignore the member attributes set for my class.

This is my sample code

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;

namespace CodeDomTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static CodeCompileUnit BuildHelloWorldGraph()
        {
            // Create a new CodeCompileUnit to contain
            // the program graph.
            CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();

            // Declare a new namespace called Samples.
            CodeNamespace samples = new CodeNamespace("Samples");
            // Add the new namespace to the compile unit.
            compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(samples);

            // Declare a new type called Class1.
            CodeTypeDeclaration class1 = new CodeTypeDeclaration("Class1");
            // Add the new type to the namespace type collection.
            samples.Types.Add(class1); // should be private
            Console.WriteLine("Class1 attributes: " + class1.Attributes);

            return compileUnit;
        }
        public static string GenerateCSharpCode(CodeCompileUnit compileunit)
        {
            // Generate the code with the C# code provider.
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

            // Create a TextWriter to a StreamWriter to the output file.
            StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();

            IndentedTextWriter tw = new IndentedTextWriter(strWriter, "    ");

            // Generate source code using the code provider.
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileunit, tw,
                new CodeGeneratorOptions());

            // Close the output file.
            tw.Close();

            return strWriter.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GenerateCSharpCode(BuildHelloWorldGraph()));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

```
Class1 attributes: 20482
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Samples {


    public class Class1 {
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `Attributes` for the `class1` object are set to 20482, which is the default value. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.memberattributes?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), this means the class should be private(20480) and final(2). Instead the class is generated as public.
What is happening here?

Comment: From a quick flick through the docs, perhaps you should be using `TypeAttributes` for a `CodeTypeDeclaration`? Non-nested classes cannot be private, and "final" is something applied to members, not classes (classes are "sealed")

Comment: @canton7 OK, I missed that. Setting that to `[...]NestedPrivate` indeed fixes the issue. Very weird that the object has both an `Attributes` and a `TypeAttributes` that both handle access modifiers. I know it doesn't make sense. I just wanted to understand this better. Put it in an answer and I'll gladly accept it

Comment: It is weird that `CodeTypeDeclaration` is a `CodeTypeMember`, and therefore inherits the attributes that would normally apply to members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a flick through [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks):

> The TypeAttributes property indicates the TypeAttributes values for the type declaration, which indicate the type category of the type.

Looking further at [TypeAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codetypedeclaration.typeattributes):

> The Attributes property is a side effect of the CodeTypeDeclaration class inheriting from CodeTypeMember so that classes can be nested. **The flags in the TypeAttributes property should be used instead of the flags in the Attributes property.**

(Emphasis mine).

So it looks like you should be applying `TypeAttributes.Sealed`, etc.

Also note that "private" only applies to nested classes (and members), while "final" normally refers to members: "sealed" is the term for classes.